# How to save financial data to a file in mathematica?

Tags: import, export, wolfram-mathematica

I want to save the financial data I get from the following code:

```
data = FinancialData["GE","OHLCV", "Jan. 1, 2000"];
```

The format is:

> {{yy, mm, dd}, {O, H, L, C, V}}

I want 2 columns, one for the {**date**}, other for the {**O**, **H**, **L**, **C**, **V**} but inside the second column I want to treat each individual value (like a list?)

I have tried:

```
Export[dir <> filename <> ".csv", data];
data1 = Import[dir <> filename <> ".csv", "Table"];
```

And also with other formats, "List", etc.

The problem is that I have a running program to backtest the data and it works fine when I get it from FinancialData but I just can't find a way to export and import like if I did the FinancialData...

For example I can't do thinks like:

```
C = Table[data1[[i]][[2]][[4]], {i, 1, n}];
```

(Of course everything works if I put data, instead of data1)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you export to `csv` when you want to keep the *Mathematica* list structure intact? Please try the following

```
data = FinancialData["GE", "OHLCV", "Jan. 1, 2000"];

Export["tmp/test.m", data]
data2 = Import["tmp/test.m"];
```

and you will see that

```
data2 == data
```

gives `True`

Comment: This really solved my problem, thanks! I dind't know about the ".m" format

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what you are trying to accomplish, presumably some external program needs to read the data??

you might do

```
Export["file.csv", Flatten[data,{2}]]
```

then partition it when you read it back:

```
 {#[[;;3]],#[[4;;]]}&/@Import["file.csv"]
```

Comment: d2 = ToExpression@Transpose[Import["file.csv"]]; data == d2  (* True *)